# When I unplug the charger at a 100% charge the top right battery indicator says that it's on 85% charge

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

[When the charger is unplugged it shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqEip.jpg)

[But when the charger is plugged in it shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nb5y.jpg)

I'm running ubuntu 20.10 on my thinkpad t460s with 8gbs of ram, an intel i5 6200u and a 250gb ssd, and when I unplug the charger the top right battery indicator, it says that my laptop is on 85% charge, but in the power settings it shows that the battery (and the extra battery) is at 100% charge. Why would this happen, or what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Depend on how old the laptop is and how was the battery used/charged. Could be a faulty battery.

Comment: That or you previously used a Lenovo proprietary software in Windows that caps the maximum charge for the batteries (the reasoning is not allowing it to fully charge it extends the life of the battery).